# How can I create localhost with xampp for php codes?

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

I've already done this but it doesn't work

I have a localhost for my WordPress
And everytime I try to make a new one it just doesn't let me to have multiple localhosts

Where did I go wrong?
Im using visual studio code as my code editor
Do I have to set any specific setting?

Comment: Surely `localhost` is just a quick way of specifying 127.0.0.1, so I can't see how you would expect to be able to have "multiple localhosts" as they'll all point to the same address. I may have misunderstood the question - can you be a bit more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: You mean you want multiple instances of WordPress in your local machine? You can use one host for that, but you can make new virtual directories in apache to host each instance

Comment: When I put the address "localhost"it just shows my WP panel,I cant run my php codes,thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

First, you must be sure about how "localhost" works.
Try to search about socket and [Apache Virtual Host](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-20-04), I believe it´ll help you.

About your problem....
Are you using Xampp? If so, you can try to split your multiples projects in different folders (all inside httpdocs), so the access will be like localhost/proj-a and localhost/proj-b

If you´re using Docker or if you really need a full unique URL without folders.... try to set up your Docker, Nginx, Apache, or the tool you´re using to start in a new port (remember 80 is the default), so assuming your Docker will use the port 8080, your access will be localhost:8080.

If it´s not clean, please try to read about my 2 suggestions and after that give us more details that someone for sure will help.

Comment: I need a localhost for my php codes

Comment: Im using xampp,so I create the folder "php" in htdocs

Comment: But when I put the address "localhost/php" it show 404 error on my WordPress panel  that I created on vhost

Comment: If you´re using "localhost/php" you don´t need to configure a virtual host. Try to remove the virtual host configuration and try again.

Remember your application (WP) must be configured to answer to the same URL (localhost/php)

Comment: Thats the problem,I cant echo my php codes, everytime I put the address "localhost"on my browser it just shows my WP panel,I think it cant find my php direction

Comment: Did you remove all VirtualHost configurations? If so try to uninstall and install again Xampp

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the .htaccess file, the localhost/php path must be allowed in it.
For testing, you can rename the .htaccess file on htdocs/localhost.
The .htaccess file may be hidden.

Comment: How can I give access to that?